# Rename Xml Tag name of serializing List of obect

Tags: c#

I have following classes

```
public class MyClass
{
    [XmlElement("PersonList")]
    public List<Data> DataList { get; set; }
}

// Rename this to 'Person'
public class Data
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

i want to `seriPersonalize` the 'MyClass' using Xml `Serializer` and i want following output xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MyData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<PersonList>
    <Person>
        <Name>abc</Name>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <Name>pqr</Name>
    </Person>
    <Person>
        <Name>xyz</Name>
    </Person>
</PersonList>
</MyData>
```

Please help to get this xml structure using `XmlElement` or `XmlRoot` to rename the tags

Comment: So what happened when you *tried* using `[XmlElement]` on the `DataList` property? (You apparently know about it...) What do you currently get?

Comment: @JonSkeet yes `[XmlElement]` on the `DataList` works **fine** but how to rename `Data`??

Comment: @JonSkeet i get this

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MyData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<PersonList>
 <Data>
  <Name>abc</Name>
 </Data>
 <Data>
  <Name>pqr</Name>
 </Data>
 <Data>
  <Name>xyz</Name>
 </Data>
</PersonList>
</MyData>`

Comment: Please put that in the *question* rather than as a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can achieve this using

> XmlArray

and

> XmlArrayItem

```
public class MyClass
{
    [XmlArray("PersonList")]
    [XmlArrayItem("Person")]
    public List<Data> DataList { get; set; }
}

public class Data
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName="Person")]
public class Data
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlrootattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: above code gives following out out<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MyData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<PersonList> 
  <Name>abc</Name>
</PersonList>
<PersonList> 
  <Name>pqr</Name>
</PersonList>
<PersonList> 
  <Name>xyz</Name>
</PersonList>
</MyData>